# How do I search Recent Calls on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, search, history

I am looking for a phone number in my history. All I know is the area code 808, which will narrow it down immensely, and its having occurred between a month and two months ago.

How can I search the call history for the area code?

iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1.2

Comment: It would help to know what phone - but if it's an iPhone my guess is you can't, other than scrolling down the list. Spotlight only seems find numbers that are also in your contacts.

Comment: Would it not be assumed that the default phone on an Apple Q&A page would be the iPhone? ... moreover on other brands of phone searching through contacts and history is trivial! Apple omit such elementary functionality? Astonishing! Infuriating!!

Comment: It would indeed be reasonable to assume that the default phone on an Apple page is an iPhone, but knowing the model and OS version helps people look for an answer, and also sometimes people post off-topic questions here. Similarly, you could be talking about searching for recent calls in Skype running on a Mac, or in some other program; it is better to specify, but yes, your defaults do make sense.

Comment: Apple design is very often horrible. Number of recent calls in recent list is limited, no ability to search recent list, after looking up a contact, contact info does not include list of recent calls made to that contact, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Searching for contact numbers is possible through FaceTime. Type some digits of the that contact number into the address bar and Facetime will automatically search recent calls. You have to connect your iPhone to a Mac where your iCloud account should be logged in then FaceTime will automatically sync all your call history from your iPhone and then your are able to search a contact number through typing some digits in recent dial call's text field inside FaceTime.

Comment: This answer, as written, is very difficult to understand.  In order to prevent it from being flagged as 'poor quality', please read [answer] and then [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/285174/edit) your answer to make it clear, concise, and self-contained.

Comment: Sorry for bad english,